# Не работает модальное окно SqueezeBox Joomla 2.5 в Chrome и Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, google-chrome

Перестало работать стандартное модальное окошко Joomla в Chrome и Firefox. 
Окно открывается но данные в него не загружаются. Ссылка:

```
<a id="sortWindow"  href="/modules/mod_City_Catalog/sortWindow.php" class="modal" rel="{size:{x:250,y:200}}">Выбор</a>
```

Библиотека подключается стандартно `JHTML::_('behavior.modal');`

Использовал множество раз на сайте и до сегодняшнего дня все работало.

Ошибка похоже в библиотеке mootools, в консоли следующая ошибка:

```
Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил следующим образом

```
rel="{handler:'iframe',size:{x:250,y:200}}
```

Прописал хендлер и все заработало.